Questions about the availability of libgcov.a in building cross-toolchains
Build environment:

msys2-mingw64
gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
src
binutils-2.34
gcc-11.4.0
gmp-6.1.0
isl-0.18
mpc-1.0.3
mpfr-3.1.4
newlib-4.1.0
config

#! /bin/bash

TOP_PATH="$(pwd)"
TARGET_GCC=arm-ACoreOS-eabi

INSTALL_PATH=${TOP_PATH}/install
BUILD_PATH=${TOP_PATH}/build

set -e
set -x

#Clean up the compilation process file
rm -rf ${INSTALL_PATH} ${BUILD_PATH}
mkdir ${INSTALL_PATH} ${BUILD_PATH}

#Libs
mkdir ${BUILD_PATH}/gmp
cd ${BUILD_PATH}/gmp
../../src/gmp-6.1.0/configure --build=x86-w64-mingw32 --prefix=${INSTALL_PATH} --enable-static --disable-shared
make all -j16
make install

mkdir ${BUILD_PATH}/isl
cd ${BUILD_PATH}/isl
../../src/isl-0.18/configure --build=x86-w64-mingw32 --prefix=${INSTALL_PATH} --enable-static --disable-shared  --with-gmp-prefix=${INSTALL_PATH}
make all -j16
make install

mkdir ${BUILD_PATH}/mpfr
cd ${BUILD_PATH}/mpfr
../../src/mpfr-3.1.4/configure --build=x86-w64-mingw32 --prefix=${INSTALL_PATH} --enable-static --disable-shared --with-gmp=${INSTALL_PATH}
make all -j16
make install

mkdir ${BUILD_PATH}/mpc
cd ${BUILD_PATH}/mpc
../../src/mpc-1.0.3/configure --build=x86-w64-mingw32 --prefix=${INSTALL_PATH} --enable-static --disable-shared  --with-gmp=${INSTALL_PATH} --with-mpfr=${INSTALL_PATH}
make all -j16
make install

#binutils
mkdir ${BUILD_PATH}/binutils
cd ${BUILD_PATH}/binutils
../../src/binutils-2.34/configure --build=x86-w64-mingw32 --target=${TARGET_GCC} --prefix=${INSTALL_PATH} --disable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-static --enable-shared
make all -j16
make install

#gcc all-gcc
mkdir ${BUILD_PATH}/gcc
cd ${BUILD_PATH}/gcc
../../src/gcc-11.4.0/configure --target=${TARGET_GCC} --prefix=${INSTALL_PATH} --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-gcov --enable-plugin --enable-sanitizer --disable-shared --disable-nls --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-pkgversion='Anban ABFast GCC 2024-04-28' --disable-threads --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-bootstrap --disable-multilib --with-gmp=${INSTALL_PATH} --with-mpfr=${INSTALL_PATH} --with-mpc=${INSTALL_PATH} --with-isl=${INSTALL_PATH} --with-newlib --with-headers=/home/anban/src/newlib-4.1.0/newlib/libc/include --with-native-system-header=${INSTALL_PATH}/arm-ACoreOS-eabi/sys-include 'CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-O2 -g -fno-short-enums -mhard-float -mfpu=vfpv3 ' 'CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-O2 -g -fno-short-enums -mhard-float -mfpu=vfpv3' 'GOCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-O2 -g -fno-short-enums -mhard-float -mfpu=vfpv3' -v
make all-gcc -j16
make install all-gcc

#newlib
export PATH=$PATH:${INSTALL_PATH}/bin
mkdir ${BUILD_PATH}/newlib
cd ${BUILD_PATH}/newlib
../../src/newlib-4.1.0/configure --target=${TARGET_GCC} --prefix=${INSTALL_PATH} --disable-multilib --disable-werror --disable-threads 'CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-O2 -g -fno-short-enums -mhard-float -mfpu=vfpv3 ' 'CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-O2 -g -fno-short-enums -mhard-float -mfpu=vfpv3 ' 'GOCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-O2 -g -fno-short-enums -mhard-float -mfpu=vfpv3'
make all -j16
make install

#gcc all
cd ${BUILD_PATH}/gcc
make all -j16
make install all

echo ${TARGET_GCC} Compile complete!!!

I am using the above build environment to prepare to build the arm cross-compilation toolchain. The build is successful but the generated libgcov.a is not available.
Disassemble the object code after compiling it using the built toolchain to see the __gcov_init implementation below
                  __gcov_merge_add:
0000000084016480:   bx lr
 33               void __gcov_init (struct gcov_info *p __attribute__ ((unused))) {}
                  __gcov_init:
0000000084016484:   bx lr

The corresponding gcc source code is as follows:
enter image description here
How to control gcc source code related to gcov compilation macros so that the gcc toolchain built out can have a normal libgcov.a(after calling __gcov_flush can output *.gcda files)
